# Interface adaptor to interface fragment android

Tags: java, android, interface

Adaptor class that provides an interface:

```
public class Adaptor{

    private ItemCLickCallback itemCLickCallback;

        public interface ItemCLickCallback {
            void onItemClick(int p);
            void onSecItemClick(int p);
        }
        public void setItemCLickCallback(final ItemCLickCallback itemCLickCallback){
            this.itemCLickCallback = itemCLickCallback;
        }}


public class Overview extends Fragment implements Adaptor.ItemCLickCallback{

         @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_overview, container, false);
        Adaptor adaptor = new Adaptor(mijnwinkels, this.getActivity());
adaptor.setItemCLickCallback(this);
        return view;
    }

@Override
    public void onItemClick(int p) {
}
    @Override
    public void onSecItemClick(int p) {
      // On click: send data to database, remove data from database
      // Needs methods that should be implemented in my activity, cant be linked to the activity
    }}
```

So. The methods that are overwritten in my fragment need methods that should be located in my activity, those methods need the data from the fragment. Usually I would use an interface to do this, but these methods are already part of an interface from another class, so how can I put them in an interface so I can do everything from my activity? Thank you

Comment: All that code that creates the Bundle can be extracted to a method that accepts a Winkel object

Comment: Anyways, `onSuccess` of what? Please show a [mcve]

Comment: @cricket_007 Added some commentary to explain further. My fragment is currently implementing the interface from my adaptor, but I want to create a new Interface in my activity basically. OnSecItemCLick() will have code that gets and sets data to my database, but since I need to use that code somewhere else too (in the same activity) I want it to be in the activity and I don't know how to do that because the methods are part of the interface in my adaptor, implemented in my fragment

Comment: You could also make `Winkel` implement Parcelable, then you don't even need to explicitly put each data into Bundle extras

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand explanations very well. You have 3 classes and some amount of interfaces. It sounds like you are trying to reduce duplicate code. Extracting common functionality to additional methods is frequently how you do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seems to mostly deal with removing duplicate code from the interface, so here's some suggestions.

You don't need to add a whole new Adaptor when you get your data in the onSuccess.

```
private ArrayList<Winkel> mijnwinkels;
private Adaptor mAdaptor;

onCreateView() { 
    //... Other code 
    mijnwinkels = new  ArrayList<Winkel>();
    // mRecyclerView =... 
    mAdaptor = new Adaptor(mijnwinkels, this.getActivity());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity()));
    mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new VerticalSpace(30));
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adaptor);
    adaptor.setItemCLickCallback(this);
   // etc... 
} 

@Override
public void onSuccess(ArrayList<Winkel> winkels) {
    mijnwinkels.clear();
    mijnwinkels.addAll(winkels);
    mAdaptor.notifyDatasetChanged(); // something like this... Not sure how RecyclerView does it 
 }
```

If you make `Winkel implements Parcelable` and implement the necessary code for that, you remove some lines there.

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(int p) {
    Winkel winkel = (Winkel) mijnwinkels.get(p);

     Bundle detailsBundle = new Bundle();
    detailsBundle.putExtra(EXTRA_WINKEL,winkel);

    Details detail= new Details();
    detail.setArguments(detailsBundle);
    this.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.mycontainer,detail,null)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
  }
```

Though, really, all this can be written as its own method.

```
public static void showWinkel(Winkel winkel, FragmentManager fm) {
    Bundle detailsBundle = new Bundle();
    detailsBundle.putExtra(EXTRA_WINKEL,winkel);

    Details detail= new Details();
    detail.setArguments(detailsBundle);
    fm.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.mycontainer,detail)
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit();
}
```

And called from anywhere

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(int p) {
    showWinkel(mijnwinkels.get(p), this.getFragmentManager());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
adaptor.setItemCLickCallback(this);
```

Once use below code for your fragment:

```
   adaptor.setItemCLickCallback(new Adaptor.ItemCLickCallback () {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(int position) {

    }

});
```

Comment: Edited my code, sorry, It wasn't clear enough. My methods are working perfectly fine, I want to avoid duplicate code (that still has to be written), but I don't know how to do it in this situation